MPU6886 with Arduino Mega 2560: Steering Angle Calculation and Drift Issue 2
I'm working on a project where I need to calculate the steering angle of a vehicle using an MPU6886 sensor connected to an Arduino Mega 2560. The issue I'm facing is that the steering angle drifts with each complete rotation. Here's the problem in detail:
At first the angle is stable at 0degree once the steering is moved along with the sensor the and stopped at the random position anywhere between 0 to 360 the angle drifts by 1 degree ahead.  and provided the code below please help me for this issue??

`
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// MPU6886 I2C address
#define MPU6886_ADDR 0x68
#define MPU6886_GYRO_XOUT_H 0x43
#define MPU6886_ACCEL_XOUT_H 0x3B
#define MPU6886_ACCEL_CONFIG 0x1C
#define MPU6886_GYRO_CONFIG 0x1B

// Ethernet setup
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; // Replace with your Ethernet shield MAC address
IPAddress ip(169, 254, 5, 2); // Replace with your desired IP address
EthernetServer server(80);
IPAddress gateway(169, 254, 5, 1); // Replace with your gateway
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0); // Subnet mask
IPAddress dns(169, 254, 5, 1); // Replace with your DNS server

// Global variables
float totalAngle = 0.0;
unsigned long previousTime = 0;
float gyroZ_zero = 0.0;
const float movementThreshold = 1.0; // Threshold to detect movement (degrees per second)
unsigned long ethernetInterval = 1000; // Interval in milliseconds to send data over Ethernet
unsigned long previousEthernetTime = 0;

// Variables for steady state detection
bool isMoving = false;
unsigned long steadyStartTime = 0;
const unsigned long steadyDuration = 500; // Time in milliseconds to consider the sensor steady

// Rotation counter
int rotationCount = 0; // Count the number of complete rotations
const int maxRotations = 3; // Maximum number of rotations before stopping

// Encoder setup
int encoderPin1 = 2;
int encoderPin2 = 3;
int encoderPin3 = 18;
int encoderPin4 = 19;

volatile long encoderValue1 = 0;
volatile long encoderValue2 = 0;
volatile int lastEncoded1 = 0;
volatile int lastEncoded2 = 0;

unsigned long lastXReceivedTime = 0; // Time when the last 'X' was received
const unsigned long timeoutDuration = 2000; // Timeout duration in milliseconds

// Add recalibration interval and variables
const unsigned long recalibrationInterval = 60000; // Recalibration interval in milliseconds
unsigned long lastRecalibrationTime = 0;

void updateEncoder1() {
    int MSB = digitalRead(encoderPin1);  // MSB = most significant bit
    int LSB = digitalRead(encoderPin2);  // LSB = least significant bit
    int encoded1 = (MSB << 1) | LSB;  // converting the 2 pin value to single number
    int sum = (lastEncoded1 << 2) | encoded1;  // adding it to the previous encoded value

    if (sum == 0b1101 || sum == 0b0100 || sum == 0b0010 || sum == 0b1011)
        encoderValue1++;
    if (encoderValue1 == 10000) {
        encoderValue1 = 0;
    }

    if (sum == 0b1110 || sum == 0b0111 || sum == 0b0001 || sum == 0b1000)
        encoderValue1--;
    if (encoderValue1 == 10000) {
        encoderValue1 = 0;
    }

    lastEncoded1 = encoded1;  // store this value for next time
}

void updateEncoder2() {
    int MSB2 = digitalRead(encoderPin3);  // MSB = most significant bit
    int LSB2 = digitalRead(encoderPin4);  // LSB = least significant bit
    int encoded = (MSB2 << 1) | LSB2;  // converting the 2 pin value to single number
    int sum2 = (lastEncoded2 << 2) | encoded;  // adding it to the previous encoded value

    if (sum2 == 0b1101 || sum2 == 0b0100 || sum2 == 0b0010 || sum2 == 0b1011)
        encoderValue2++;
    if (encoderValue2 == 10000) {
        encoderValue2 = 0;
    }

    if (sum2 == 0b1110 || sum2 == 0b0111 || sum2 == 0b0001 || sum2 == 0b1000)
        encoderValue2--;
    if (encoderValue2 == 10000) {
        encoderValue2 = 0;
    }

    lastEncoded2 = encoded;  // store this value for next time
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Wire.begin(); // Initialize I2C communication

    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, dns, gateway, subnet); // Initialize Ethernet with MAC, IP, DNS, Gateway, and Subnet
    server.begin(); // Start Ethernet server
  
    previousTime = millis(); // Initialize time tracking

    // Initialize MPU6886
    Wire.beginTransmission(MPU6886_ADDR);
    Wire.write(0x6B); // Power management register
    Wire.write(0x00); // Wake up MPU6886
    if (Wire.endTransmission() != 0) {
        Serial.println("Failed to initialize MPU6886!");
        while (1);
    }

    // Set accelerometer sensitivity to ±2g
    Wire.beginTransmission(MPU6886_ADDR);
    Wire.write(MPU6886_ACCEL_CONFIG);
    Wire.write(0x00); // 00: ±2g
    Wire.endTransmission();

    // Set gyroscope sensitivity to ±250°/s
    Wire.beginTransmission(MPU6886_ADDR);
    Wire.write(MPU6886_GYRO_CONFIG);
    Wire.write(0x00); // 00: ±250°/s
    Wire.endTransmission();

    // Calibrate the gyro to zero
    calibrateGyro();

    // Initialize encoder pins
    pinMode(encoderPin1, INPUT);   // Set encoder pins as input
    pinMode(encoderPin2, INPUT);
    pinMode(encoderPin3, INPUT);
    pinMode(encoderPin4, INPUT);

    digitalWrite(encoderPin1, HIGH); //turn pullup resistor on
    digitalWrite(encoderPin2, HIGH); //turn pullup resistor on
    digitalWrite(encoderPin3, HIGH); //turn pullup resistor on
    digitalWrite(encoderPin4, HIGH); //turn pullup resistor on
    
    // Attach interrupts for encoders
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoderPin1), updateEncoder1, CHANGE);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoderPin2), updateEncoder1, CHANGE);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoderPin3), updateEncoder2, CHANGE);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoderPin4), updateEncoder2, CHANGE);
}

void calibrateGyro() {
    const int numCalibrationReadings = 1000;
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numCalibrationReadings; i++) {
        int16_t gyroZ; 
        readGyroData(&gyroZ);
        sum += gyroZ;
    }
    gyroZ_zero = sum / (float)numCalibrationReadings; // Set the zero point for gyro readings
    totalAngle = 0.0; // Ensure totalAngle starts at 0
}

void readGyroData(int16_t *gyroZ) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(MPU6886_ADDR);
    Wire.write(MPU6886_GYRO_XOUT_H);
    if (Wire.endTransmission(false) != 0) {
        return;
    }

    Wire.requestFrom(MPU6886_ADDR, 2); // Request 2 bytes of data
    if (Wire.available() == 2) {
        *gyroZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // Combine high byte and low byte
    }
}

void readAccelData(int16_t *accelZ) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(MPU6886_ADDR);
    Wire.write(MPU6886_ACCEL_XOUT_H);
    if (Wire.endTransmission(false) != 0) {
        return;
    }

    Wire.requestFrom(MPU6886_ADDR, 2); // Request 2 bytes of data
    if (Wire.available() == 2) {
        *accelZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // Combine high byte and low byte
    }
}

float getComplementaryFilterReading(float dt) {
    int16_t gyroZ;
    readGyroData(&gyroZ);
    int16_t accelZ;
    readAccelData(&accelZ);

    // Convert gyro Z to degrees per second
    float gyroZ_degPerSec = (gyroZ - gyroZ_zero) / 131.0; // Adjust based on sensitivity

    // Calculate angle from gyro
    float angleFromGyro = totalAngle + gyroZ_degPerSec * dt;

    // Calculate angle from accelerometer (assuming upright position)
    float angleFromAccel = atan2(accelZ, sqrt(pow(accelZ, 2))) * 180.0 / PI;

    // Complementary filter
    float alpha = 0.98; // Tuning parameter (0 < alpha < 1)
    totalAngle = alpha * angleFromGyro + (1 - alpha) * angleFromAccel;

    // Normalize totalAngle to 0-360 degrees range
    totalAngle = fmod(totalAngle, 360.0);
    if (totalAngle < 0) totalAngle += 360.0;

    return totalAngle;
}

void loop() {
    unsigned long currentTime = millis();
    float dt = (currentTime - previousTime) / 1000.0; // Time in seconds
    previousTime = currentTime;

    // Gyro angle calculation using complementary filter
    float angle = getComplementaryFilterReading(dt);

    // Detect movement
    if (abs(angle) > movementThreshold) {
        isMoving = true;
        steadyStartTime = currentTime;
    } else if (isMoving && (currentTime - steadyStartTime > steadyDuration)) {
        isMoving = false;
    }

    // Update angle only if moving
    if (isMoving) {
        // Check for complete rotations
        if (angle > 0 && totalAngle >= 360.0) {
            rotationCount++;
            totalAngle -= 360.0; // Reset totalAngle to avoid multiple counts
        }
        
        // Check for crossing from 0 to 360
        if (angle < 0 && totalAngle < 1.0 && totalAngle > 359.0) {
            rotationCount++;
        }
    }

    // Stop counting after reaching the maximum rotations
    if (rotationCount >= maxRotations) {
        isMoving = false; // Stop updating if max rotations reached
    }

    // Check for Ethernet client and incoming data
    EthernetClient client = server.available();
    if (client) {
        // Calculate angles from encoder values
        int angle1 = encoderValue1 * 0.036; // 360/10000 * encoder value
        int angle2 = encoderValue2 * 0.036; // 360/10000 * encoder value
        String angle1String = String(abs(angle1));
        String angle2String = String(abs(angle2));
        
        // Check if client has data available
        if (client.available()) {
            char c = client.read(); // Read the incoming byte
            if (c == 'X') { // If 'X' is received
                // Send the formatted data
                client.print(totalAngle); // Total Angle
                client.print(","); // Separator
                client.print(angle1String); // Encoder Value 1
                client.print(","); // Separator
                client.print(angle2String); // Encoder Value 2
                client.print(";"); // End of message
                
                lastXReceivedTime = millis(); // Update the last received time for 'X'
            } else if (c == 'K') { // If 'K' is received
                totalAngle = 0.0; // Reset totalAngle
                encoderValue1 = 0; // Reset encoder value 1
                encoderValue2 = 0; // Reset encoder value 2
                client.stop(); // Stop the client
            }
        }
    }

    // Check for timeout
    if (millis() - lastXReceivedTime > timeoutDuration) {
        totalAngle = 0.0; // Reset totalAngle if 'X' is not received within the timeout duration
    }

    // Periodic recalibration
    if (currentTime - lastRecalibrationTime > recalibrationInterval) {
        calibrateGyro(); // Recalibrate the gyro
        `lastRecalibrationTime = currentTime; `// Update the recalibration time
    }

    // Removed delay for continuous updates
}`
type here

